# Cautery Pen.. plug in?

Tags: batteries, dc, wiring

I'm interested in turning my cautery pen (one of those with the replaceable batteries) into something that's DC powered through an AC adapter.

I've figured out the internal wiring for the pen, and by plugging it into one of the shop power supplies, I can tell that it uses 3V at around 3-3.3A to get the glow i want for my application.  I'm looking for something more portable than the shop power supply.

Would it be possible/worth it to modify something like this to power this thing?  [https://www.amazon.com/Type-C-Charger-Security-Google-Include/dp/B01IHE38Z4/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01IHE38Z4)

What would be necessary to do so?  I know i'm probably looking for a potentiometer to give me some fine tuning ability as well.. or am I just looking at it way the wrong way?

Comment: What is a cautery pen?

Comment: It's for cauterising things.

Comment: its like a soldering iron, only much hotter, much thinner, and easier to use for some things.  http://boviemed.com/products_aaroncauteries_changeatip.asp

Answer (score 1):

For the most compact solution you could just put a barrel jack in the end of the pen and plug in [a 3V power supply](https://www.amazon.ca/ZOZO-Universal-Regulated-Replacement-Electronic/dp/B01D9FB182/ref=sr_1_cc_1?s=aps&ie=UTF8&qid=1488371784&sr=1-1-catcorr&keywords=power+supply+3V) with no additional regulator.

If you don't need the ability to adjust, you are probably better off using a regulator that provides 3V so you don't have to step the voltage down further.

If you want the ability to adjust then you would want a higher voltage supply, perhaps 12V, with a step-down regulator like [this one.](http://www.ebay.com/itm/10-PCS-LM2596-DC-DC-buck-adjustable-step-down-Power-Supply-Converter-module-/221920170517?hash=item33ab791215:g:5zEAAOSw~bFWKKJO)

A pot in series with the power would work assuming it is rated for the power, but because of the current level you are dealing with is not a good solution.  The pot would be very large and it is very inefficient.

WARNING: You can't use a cautery pen on people with this modification.  You would need a supply with proper isolation and medical certification.  I'm assuming you are doing this for some other purpose.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is most 3v power supplies just dont put out enough amperage for the application, i'm pretty sure.

Comment: something like this then, with the medical cert?  http://www.trcelectronics.com/View/Protek/PMP15M-10.shtml

Comment: The adjustable supply I linked specifies a 12W rating, which should mean 4A @3V, but maybe not.  You might need to try it to see.  It has a built in voltage adjustment, although not infinitely variable.  The next step 4.5V may be too much, and I believe the pen is resistive, so a higher voltage would draw more current (more than 12W), so it's probably not a suitable setting.  That supply you linked is a good start and a requirement if used on humans, but you would still need to get certification of the device first also (from my understanding).

Comment: I assume you mean by "using on humans" you mean as a body-modification device such as in a tattoo shop?  Just so we're on the same page.

Comment: Well, I didn't know they were being used for that also, but anytime it would come in contact with a person, there would be risk of shock or electrocution.  If there is an electrical surge on the mains it may pass through to the tip if the supply is not properly isolated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be more convenient to just have a multi-station LiPO cell charger and swap the cell whenever it stops heating enough. A LED indicator connected to brownout chip at a suitable voltage could be a good indicator to swap before reaching the LiPO minimum cell voltage.

This would be a wireless solution as the device was intended to be used.  it would be a lot safer from a human electrical device perspective as well.